# iOS detect document edges

Tags: ios, image-processing, detection, gpuimage, edge-detection

I'm working with GPUImage to detect document edges, using `GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector` without any previous filter.

I'm discarding returned lines that are similar between them, and then I'm calculating the points of intersection.

**With those points I want to find possible rectangles, but I can't figure out how.**

I found this post answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502570/3708095 that says:

> The steps would be:
>
> 1. Edge detection using Sobel filter.
> 2. Hough transform to find all straight lines in the image.
> 3. Look at all parallel lines and then all lines 90 degrees to those parallel line pairs, to find possible rectangles.
> 4. Pick the rectangle you like best. This could be by area, or by being best aligned to the phone, or you require that all edges are
>      inside the visible camera image, or some other method.

Said that way seems quite easy to pick up the rectangles, but I wonder **how I can find all the rectangles in an efficient way** to be fast enough to do it real time, since using 4 nested loops to find all combinations of those corners is a really expensive calculation.

Besides, step 3 doesn't seem to be as easy as [unapiedra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461597/unapiedra) describes. I think that you can find multiple parallel lines in an image... **Am I misunderstanding something?**